# Anti-symmetric $(0, 2)$ tensor in 3D space is completely characterized by a vector

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Consider an anti-symmetric $(0, 2)$ tensor $B_{ij} = −B_{ji}$ in 3D space. Show that any such tensor is completely characterized by a vector

Please help me on this!

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Hint: Consider that a skew-symmetric tensor in 3D is fully specified by  prescribing only three independent components in a basis. Three (the diagonal components) are 0, and three others are determined by the fact that it is skew-symmetric.